# Winform webbrowser automation is not clicking Button

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to automate a winforms webbrowser control to fill formulars on external webpages. While testing with the google-page i can't click the searchbutton.

I'm not getting an Error, it just does nothing. I've also checked if the HTMLElement is found.
I think i'm completely blind, so here is my code.

Can u tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
    currentPage currentPageV;

    enum currentPage
    {
        GoogleSearch,
        SearchResults
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.de");
        currentPageV = currentPage.GoogleSearch;
    }

    private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentPage.GoogleSearch == currentPageV)
        {
            currentPageV = currentPage.SearchResults;
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("q")[0].SetAttribute("value", "Some Text");
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("btnK")[0].InvokeMember("click");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try capitalizing "click" to "Click"?

Comment: yes but unfortunately without success.

Comment: Okay I solved it dirty with pressing ESC (SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");) to supress the autocomplete-window.
Do you have a better solution or can you tell me why the element isn't clickable when the dropdown hovers, because the element is still present in the Document?!